# $x = \sin θ + \cos θ$ and $y = \sin θ − \cos θ$. Prove that this expression is independent of $θ $by simplifying it

Tags: trigonometry

> Let $x = \sin θ + \cos θ$ and $y = \sin θ − \cos θ$. Prove that this expression is independent of $θ$ by simplifying it.

My first problem is that I don't know what 'independent of $θ$' even means. Am I supposed to solve it simultaneously or add the equations together?

Comment: It would truly help to know what "this expression" is! Cheers!

Comment: x = sin θ + cos θ and y = sin θ − cos θ

Comment: What do you mean by "independent of $\theta$"?

Comment: Normally I would view the expression as defining a point $(x,y)$, which is clearly not independent of $\theta$.  An expression independent of $\theta$ would be $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta$ for which the value is the same whatever $\theta$ you plug in.

Comment: Where did the question come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean to express this curve independently from $\theta$ and in a way to find a function $f$ such that $$f(x,y)=0$$, then we can write$$x^2+y^2{=(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2+(\sin\theta-\cos\theta)^2\\=1+2\sin\theta\cos\theta+1-2\sin\theta\cos\theta\\=2}$$
which is a circle with radius $\sqrt 2$ centered at $(0,0)$.

Comment: The question is very badly stated, but this is a reasonable guess for what is wanted.

Comment: Yes, thank you. i understand what the question is trying to ask now !

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

In general for $x=a\cos t+b\sin t$

and $y=c\cos t+d\sin t$

Solve the two simultaneous equations for $\sin t,\cos t$

Then use $$\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1$$ to eliminate $t$

Can you recognize $a,b,c,d$ here?

Answer (score 2):

$x = sin(\theta) + cos(\theta)$

Hence:

$$\sqrt2/2 \cdot x = \sqrt2/2 \cdot sin(\theta) + \sqrt2/2 \cdot cos(\theta)$$
$$    =cos(\frac \pi 4) \cdot cos(\theta) + sin(\frac \pi 4) \cdot sin(\theta)$$
$$    =cos(\theta) \cdot cos(\frac \pi 4) + sin(\theta) \cdot sin(\frac \pi 4)$$
$$    =cos(\theta - \frac \pi 4)$$

$y = sin(\theta) - cos(\theta)$

Hence:

$$\sqrt2/2 \cdot y = \sqrt2/2 \cdot sin(\theta) - \sqrt2/2 \cdot cos(\theta)$$
$$    =cos(\frac \pi 4) \cdot sin(\theta) - sin(\frac \pi 4) \cdot cos(\theta)$$
$$    =sin(\theta) \cdot cos(\frac \pi 4) - cos(\theta) \cdot sin(\frac \pi 4)$$
$$    =sin(\theta - \frac \pi 4)$$

From that, you can easily derive:

$$x^2/2 + y^2/2 = 1$$ or:

$$x^2 + y^2 = 2$$

This means: you can write an equation, linking $x$ and $y$, without any $\theta$.